# how to hide or remove extjs line chart axes (xaxis or yaxis) ticks

Tags: extjs4

I have requirement to hide the x axis (ticks and labels) .Anybody knows please tell me how to hide the ticks,I am able to hide the labels,but not the ticks,Basically my chart x axis will keep grow(more than 150 steps(ticks) with in 20 minutes),If i look at steps(ticks) alone (label hidden)in xaxis it so weird to see....

so please anybody have an idea to remove this ticks or steps

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

We have "**dashSize**" config in **Axis** class:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Axis-cfg-dashSize

You have to set it to **0** like this:

```
axes: {
    ...
    dashSize: 0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for this for ExtJS 5, it's now

```
axes: [{
   type: 'numeric',
   ...
}, {
   type: 'category',
   style: { majorTickSize : 0},
   ...
}]
```